# Confusion with inputs and targets for a neural network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Recently I've posted many question s regarding a character recognition program that I am making. I thought I had it working fully until today. I think it has to do with my training of the network. What follows is an explanation of how I think the training and simulation procedure goes.

Give these two images

targets

[image]

inputs

[image]

I want to train the network to recognize the letter D. Note that before this is done, I've processed the images into a binary matrix. For training I use

```
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
```

where instead of inputs I was targets because I want to train the network to recognize all the letters in the target image.

I then run

```
outputs = sim(net,inputs);
```

where inputs is the image with the letter "D", or an image with any other letter that is in ABCD. The basic premise here is that I want to train the network to recognized all the letters in ABCD, then choose any letter A, B, C, or D and see if the network recognizes this choosen letter.

Question:

Am I correct with the training procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it greatly depends on how you implemented your neural network. Although regarding the question you're asking I guess you didn't implement it yourself but used some ready made API.

Anyways, you should first understand the tools you use before you use them (here neural networks).

A neural network takes an input and performs linear or non-linear transformations of the input and returns an output.

Inputs and outputs are always numeric values. However they may represent any kind of data.

Inputs can be:

- Pixels of an image
- Real valued or integer attributes
- Categories
- etc.

In your case the inputs are the pixels of your character images (your binary matrices).

Outputs can be:

- Classes (if you're doing classification)
- Values (if you're doing regression)
- Next value in a time series (if you're doing time series prediction)

In your case, you're doing classification (predicting which character the inputs represent) so your output is a class.

For you to understand how the network is trained, I'll first explain how to use it once it's trained and then what it implies for the training phase.

So once you've trained you network, you will give it the binary matrix representing your image and it will output the class (the character) which will be (for example): 0 for A, 1 for B, 2 for C and 3 for D. In other words, you have:

- **Input:** binary matrix (image)
- **Output:** 0,1,2 or 3 (depending on which character the network recognizes in the image)

The training phase consists in telling the network which output you would like for each input.

The type of data used during the training phase is the same as the one being used in the "prediction phase". Hence, for the training phase:

- **Inputs:** binary matrices [A,B,C,D] **(One for each letter! Very important !)**
- **Targets:** corresponding classes [0,1,2,3]

This way, you're telling the network to learn that if you give it the image of A it should output 0, if you give it the image of B it should output 1, and so on.

**Note:** You were mistaken because you thought of the "inputs" as the inputs you wanted to give the network after the training phase, when they were actually the inputs given to the network during the training phase.

Comment: Well it looks from the error message like you should actually give the inputs and targets to the network in cell arrays. If X and T are your cell arrays then each cell X{i} (i in [1,4]) is a letter in binary form (1x100 matrix) and each cell T{i} (i in [1,4]) is the singleton matrix containing either 0,1,2 or 3. This way it should work and dimensions should match.

Comment: I'm still getting errors @Dolma. I convert my input matrix to a cell matrix so that it's 4x100 cell. My target data is target = [{0},{1},{2},{3}]. I still get the same error. I tried instead making targets a column of cells.

Comment: No the input has to be a 1x4 cell array. Each cell is a 1x100 matrix. The target is also a 1x4 cell array and each of its cells is a 1x1 matrix (which is what you did).

Comment: If this doesn't work, then try using a 100x4 matrix for input, and a 1x4 matrix for the target.

Comment: I got it to work now. However, I've coded a different procedure from before I posted this question and it works much faster than the traditional training. With my procedure I train each individual letter. In other words, a neural network for each letter. When I run the simulation, I just step through each network using a letter that I want to compare ("D") and find the network that gives the best performance.

Comment: You can't do it this way, the procedure you're describing requires you to know the target value which you should only know during training, not during simulations. During simulations, you should only provide the network with your input and let it tell you what it is. Think about it, what you're doing is basically already knowing what letter it is, then going through all the networks to see which one performs best, and then using this result to see what character it is. But you already know what character it is, since you used it to choose the best network... Do you see the flaw in this logic ?

Comment: I see what you mean. At the moment, it takes on average 4 minutes to train 3 letters using the correct procedure. I really was hoping to training more than 3 letters. I can try and reduce the number of pixels (neurons) but I probably will not get as good results as I do now.

Comment: Yes this is one of the drawbacks of using feedforward networks with backpropagation, it's time consuming. However, even if it takes a while, once it's trained you can use it anytime without training it again (depending on how you store your network). And if you're really interested in this, there are other neural network architectures that can learn way faster (seconds or even less depending on your dataset size).

Comment: after training I saved the network for future use. In regards to other neural networks, I would be interested in these other types if you happen to know of them. I would like to do comparisons of these different networks.

Comment: Having tried many architectures, the one I'm really enjoying right now is ELM (Extreme Learning Machines). Basically it just looks like a regular single layer feedforward network. But the size of the hidden layer can be way bigger and still learn pretty fast. And this is because the network parameters (weight matrices and biases) are not learnt in a regular way (repeated iterations) but instead come from two simple and efficient operations: 1.Random Generation 2.Direct computation from matrix pseudo-inversion. By the way, how familiar are you with neural networks and underlying maths concepts?

Comment: I am currently in a adaptive critic designs course and we've talked about neural networks. I have read papers regarding this topic and I have a fair understanding of the mathematical concepts.

Comment: Nice! Well then I should also recommend the work of G. Hinton who did something somehow related to what you're trying to do. He used Deep Belief Networks (http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/neco.2006.18.7.1527) and trained them to recognize handwritten digits (the MNIST dataset)